# Html5 audio, loop and delay

Tags: loops, audio, delay

I am haaving some problem with a loop in a Html5 game.

I have a sound ( 4-5sec) that I wanted to play with a loop.
But between each loop I can hear the sound stop (for 0.5sec) and replay.

I read that "MP3 has a 0,25 seconds piece of silence at the start of the audio file.",
and tried this:

> start loop and sound for every sample at T = 0,25, so there were a preloading of all of the audio file, but play and loop after 0,25 seconds."

However, the delay is still present for mp3 ogg, or wave, (Firefox and chrome)

Can someone help me find a solution?